# RStudio does not clear the workspace of a package project when doing "Install and Restart"

Tags: r, build, rstudio

I have an open project (a package) in RStudio and my workspace contains variables, eg.

`a <- 1`

When I choose the menu item *Build > Install and Restart* I can see (in the console) that the R session is restarted, but the workspace is **not** cleared (I can still see that `a` is `1`):

[image]

```
Restarting R session...

> library(tryCatchLog)
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Is this possibly only a "misnomer" (the menu item was called *Build and Reload* in older RStudio versions AFAIKR)?

PS: I am using RStudio 1.1.463 on Ubuntu with R 3.4.4 and can also reproduce this on Windows with RStudio 1.2.x and R 3.6.1

**Edit 1:** The *Restore .RData* option is not the reason for that:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I have opened an issue for that: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5639

Comment: In RStudio, if you go to *Tools > Global Options...* and look under **Workspace**, is "Restore .RData into workspace at startup" selected? If so, is there a file named `./.RData` in that project directory? (For clarity, *Install and Restart* says nothing about "clearing", so I would not agree with the "misnomer" label.)

Comment: Good point and I have checked this already (see screenshot of edit 1)

Comment: That's interesting ... so I've quickly scanned the "docs" for the IDE and can nothing that really defines what it's doing (besides the self-describing "install and restart"), so I wonder if it is either a [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues) or undocumented intentional behavior (i.e., assuming that the "restart" is to side-step how some packages do not reload properly, they might do the `.RData` thing so that the user experience is most fluid).